# Refine If Else statement - or - end - Wordpress / Php

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if there is a way of refining my If Else statement in the following code:

```
<?php if ( ms_has_membership(01) ): ?>

      // HTML - USER PROFILE 

<?php global $current_user; 
      get_currentuserinfo(); 
      elseif (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author): ?>

      // HTML - USER PROFILE - (Same as above)                       

<?php else: ?>

      // LINK - Upgrade Your Subscription

<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, I need to say that if the user has a required membership ( in the first statement, then user profiles will be visible.

If the user doesn't have a required membership, but is logged in and is visiting his own profile ( is the author ), then only his own profile will be accessible.

And If the user is not logged in, nor is author, nor has a valid membership, no profiles will be visible, instead a link to upgrade subscription will show up.

My problem is that the HTML of the user profile is pretty long and I don't want to repeat the whole thing again in the second statement.

So is there a way to refine the statement, so it reads:

If the user is logged in `AND` has a valid membership `OR` is and author, then display the profile?

Could I use `||` and `&&` in one single statement??

Comment: `<?php 
     global $current_user; 
     get_currentuserinfo(); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && (ms_has_membership(01) || $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  ): ?>
    
          // HTML - USER PROFILE                       
    
    <?php else: ?>
    
          // LINK - Upgrade Your Subscription
    
    <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:- *So is there a way to refine the statement, so it reads: If the user is logged in AND has a valid membership OR is and author, then display the profile?*

You can do it in following way:-

```
<?php 
    global $current_user; 
    get_currentuserinfo(); 
?>
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && (ms_has_membership(01) || $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  ): ?>

      // HTML - USER PROFILE                       

<?php else: ?>

      // LINK - Upgrade Your Subscription

<?php endif; ?>
```